# How to pass value to layout without passing value from all functions in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In my project I am using a layout file and other view files. In my layout, there is a place to display users data. But I using this layout for different pages, so when I uses this layout for each pages, I need to pass user details from corresponding functions to view page. Is there any other short cut to pass user data only once, to layout directly??

Can anyone please reply??

Answer (score 4):

**Use Laravel View Composers**

Official [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers)

Here is an example :

*`'layout'` is your view*

```
View::composer('layout', function($view)
{
    $view->with('count', User::count());
});
```

Put this into your `"/app/start/global.php"` file